# Query to compute sum according to time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

A task consists in a start_time, date_time and workload in %.
At a given time, an employee can work on several tasks up to 100%.
Here is an example where three tasks overlap (there could be four, five…) :

[image]

Considering each time interval, the computed percentages would be: 76, 101, 50 and 25.

I wrote a algorithm taking the list of tasks in input and outputting the values, but would like to see if retrieving the sums directly from the database is more efficient. Problem is, I cannot find the right query.

Any idea fellow devs? Thanks :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Data as text tables is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could do it by first using a recursive CTE to generate the time series (assuming the DB supports that) and then left joining on the table using a between statement. If it's Postgres, I think you can also use a function to generate the series. Here's a quick Postgres example. This might need some fixes, especially on the join.

```
WITH RECURSIVE TimeSeries AS (
    SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '10 days' AS RangeStart
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RangeStart + INTERVAL '1 day'
    FROM TimeSeries
    WHERE RangeStart < NOW()
)
SELECT RangeStart, SUM(Workload) AS TotalWorkload
FROM TimeSeries
    LEFT JOIN Workload ON
        Workload.StartTimestamp BETWEEN TimeSeries.RangeStart AND TimeSeries.RangeStart + INTERVAL '1 day'
            OR Workload.EndTimestamp BETWEEN TimeSeries.RangeStart AND TimeSeries.RangeStart + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract all different periods and then sum up

```
;with
p0 as (
    select id, task, perc, t_start ts, 1 typ
    from time_periods
    UNION ALL
    select id, task, perc, t_end ts, 0 typ
    from time_periods
),
p1 as (
    select *, Lead(ts, 1) over (order by ts) te
    from p0 
),
p2 as (
    select *
    from p1
    where te is not null and ts<>te
)
select p.ts, p.te, sum(t.perc) perc_tot
from p2 p
join time_periods t on not (t.t_end<=p.ts) and not (t.t_start>=p.te)
group by p.ts, p.te
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, do I understand correctly, but probably you need

```
WITH taskdata AS (
  SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'t1','2020-09-09 08:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-09-09 16:00'::timestamp, 25),
                (1,'t2','2020-09-09 08:00:00', '2020-09-09 14:00', 51),
                (1,'t3','2020-09-09 10:00:00', '2020-09-09 18:00', 25)
          ) AS a (uid, taskid, taskstart, taskend, percent)
), checkpoints AS (
  SELECT uid, taskstart AS checkpoint
    FROM taskdata
   UNION
  SELECT uid, taskend
    FROM taskdata
)
SELECT *
  FROM checkpoints AS c
  JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT sum(percent) AS workload
           FROM taskdata AS t
          WHERE t.uid = c.uid AND
                checkpoint >= taskstart AND
                checkpoint < taskend
       ) AS p ON true
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
 uid |     checkpoint      | workload 
-----+---------------------+----------
   1 | 2020-09-09 08:00:00 |       76
   1 | 2020-09-09 10:00:00 |      101
   1 | 2020-09-09 14:00:00 |       50
   1 | 2020-09-09 16:00:00 |       25
   1 | 2020-09-09 18:00:00 |         
(5 rows)
```